# Why UPDATE permission does not work without SELECT permission in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, permissions, roles, postgresql-12

What is the purpose of `UPDATE permission` if it does not allow to update without `SELECT permission`?

Generally, I understand that update internally causes select to find target rows, but this "internal select" does not leak to a user, so it is unclear if it is a bug or there is a "deeper meaning" of that.

Assume initially `my_user` has only USAGE on `my_schema` and no grants on `my_table`

**Case 1:**

```
GRANT UPDATE ON TABLE my_schema.my_table TO my_user;

UPDATE my_table
   SET my_col = 'X';

>> SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: permission denied for table my_table
```

**Case 2:**

```
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE my_schema.my_table TO my_user;
GRANT UPDATE ON TABLE my_schema.my_table TO my_user;

UPDATE my_table
   SET my_col = 'X';

>> SUCCESS
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce that.Your actual `UPDATE` must be different. Please show the actual `UPDATE`.

Comment: See here [Privileges](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html) under UPDATE: '(In practice, any nontrivial UPDATE command will require SELECT privilege as well, since it must reference table columns to determine which rows to update, and/or to compute new values for columns.)'

Comment: But `UPDATE tab SET a=a` is an entirely different statement, and that will require the `SELECT` privilege, as it reads `a`. Either update the question or close it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your assumption about *"internal select" does not leak to a user* is erroneous.

The `returning` keyword is very powerful and can be used to proxy a `select` statement:

```sql
UPDATE my_table
SET my_col = my_col
RETURNING *;
```

--> will show the same as `select * from my_table`

However, the `select` privilege is required only because the value of `my_col` is read. If you were to use a constant instead, it would work with just the `update` privilege and it wouldn't let you return the row.

```sql
REVOKE select ON my_table FROM my_user;

update my_table set my_col =1;
UPDATE 7
update my_table set my_col =1 returning *;
ERROR:  permission denied for table test
```

Comment: you are right. What I mean is `GRANT UPDATE` should allow `UPDATE my_table
SET my_col = my_col` and prohibit `UPDATE ... RETURNING ...`; and `GRANT SELECT` should allow both.

Comment: Does a `WHERE` clause require select privelege?

Comment: @ConleyOwens see the [doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-priv.html#DDL-PRIV-UPDATE)